# installing new XP on netbook

Tags: windows-xp, installation, netbook

I have a net book that does not have a DVD reader/writer and I would like to reinstall XP - what are my options?
 I was thinking that I could just install from a external HD

Answer (score 3):

get **[WinToFlash](http://wintoflash.com/home/en/)** and transfer your XP installation CD to a USB stick or SD card.

then boot from the USB stick or SD card and proceed with the installation as usual.

*WinToFlash is freeware.*

Answer (score 0):

I used the procedure detailed in this web site:
[instructions on making USB XP install](http://wiki.eeeuser.com/windowsxpusb)

I did try the wintoflash but it didn't work in my case